# Multiple Quotes from single API call yfinance Python

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I want a quote for multiple stock symbols with one API call using Yahoo Finance.

```
import yfinance as yf

t = yf.Tickers('msft aapl goog')
print(t.info)
```

Comment: This should now work. yfinance is up. https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo Finance API is being [discontinued](https://www.quora.com/Did-Yahoo-Stock-API-shut-down).

I would suggest using the Financial Modeling Prep API as an alternative.

https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/MSFT,AAPL,GOOG

Returns the data you are looking for.

Full API Documentation can be found [here](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/#Stock-Price)

Here's a sample code downloading a json with the data:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/MSFT,AAPL,GOOG"
session = requests.session()
request = session.get(url, timeout=15)
stock_data = request.json()
```

Comment: Although it isn't the question that I asked you, it is a great solution so I up-voted and accepted.